# Generate Embed Token for a particular report from group of reports

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded

how can i generate an embed token for a particular report from the group of reports. The set of api mentioned here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/embedtoken/reports_generatetokenforcreateingroup gives all the reports from the group and I want only particular report/reports from the group.

Comment: Did you looked at the [article bellow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/embedtoken/reports_generatetokeningroup) the one you gave?

Comment: yes, i am able to get all the reports but not particular report. I have found a way to publish reports to different dashboards and embed each dashboard separately but I wanted to know if i can embed a particular report/reports

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can generate token for a particular report form a group of reports using the [Reports GenerateTokenInGroup Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/embedtoken/reports_generatetokeningroup).